# React Native - good practice: SegmentedControlIOS with ListView

Tags: javascript, ios, listview, react-native, segmentedcontrol

What are the best practices in implementing `SegmentedControllIOS` with `ListView`? I tried three solutions, all examples contain `SegmentedControllIOS` with two segments and two `ListView`. I invite you to discuss performance of this three (maybe someone could propose other, better solution). From my perspective examples are given in order from most efficient.

#### 1. Two independent dataSource, one ListView (change dataSource of ListView)

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ds1: new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,}),
      ds2: new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,}),
      index: 0,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <SegmentedControlIOS
          selectedIndex={this.state.index}
          values={['ds1', 'ds2']}
          onChange={() => this.setState({index: (this.state.index+1)%2})}
        />
        <ListView dataSource={this.state.index ? this.state.ds2 : this.state.ds1} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

#### 2. Two independent dataSource and two independent ListView

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ds1: new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,}),
      ds2: new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,}),
      index: 0,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <SegmentedControlIOS
          selectedIndex={this.state.index}
          values={['ds1', 'ds2']}
          onChange={() => this.setState({index: (this.state.index+1)%2})}
        />
        {this.state.index === 0 ?
          (<ListView dataSource={this.state.ds1} />)
        :
          (<ListView dataSource={this.state.ds2} />)
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

#### 3. One dataSource, cloneWithRows on dataSource on change index

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ds: new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,}),
      ds1: ['some', 'data'],
      ds2: ['some', 'other', 'data'],
      index: 0,
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange() {
    this.setState({
      ds: this.state.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.index ? this.ds1 : this.ds2),
      index: (this.state.index+1)%2,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <SegmentedControlIOS
          selectedIndex={this.state.index}
          values={['ds1', 'ds2']}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <ListView dataSource={this.state.ds} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Third way will be best. When you use `cloneWithRows` the `ListView` uses the `DataSource`'s `rowHasChanged` function to know what rows it now needs to re-render. Since `'some'` in the first row of `ds1` will match `'some'` in the first row of `ds2` that row will not be re-rendered.

In case 1 you're not taking advantage of the `DataSource` object's state, the `ListView` sees that it's trying to render a completely different (possibly non-comparable) data source.

In case 2 you might get some fun rendering artifacts from switching out a heavy weight scrollable component.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the use case

IMO, I will choose opt2 to start with because it's simple and easy to debug and opt1 if there's any performance issue (also check how FlatList is implemented: https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration). I feel opt1 and opt3 can leads to the case where list1 render the data of list2 and vice versa

I think, there's rarely we need to render a large of rows on the first time. Usually, we use paging (or continuous loading when scroll to the bottom) and with that loading, when you switch the segment, the data is refreshed and you don't have to render a large of rows.

The pros of opt2 is:

- easy to understand the code
- handle renderRow and selectRow also easier since you have 2 separate list.

I may go to opt1 when having any issue because on opt2, the whole list is re-mount when switching tab, which is not good (Actually, we can just hide the list instead of unmount it, will cost more memory, but faster render)

And the performance is still bad, I will consider to implement it on native side :D